# Add categories to gtsummary table

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I'm new to using R and am trying to make a summary table [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JYnv.jpg) from data that has recently been input by a research team. I am trying to use gtsummary but I can't seem to find the code needed to make the characteristics have categories, have the ages in ranges like in the example, and whilst I think I know how to change the inputs from 0,1,2 etc to having names, that is a standalone piece of code and so I am struggling to know how to incorporate that into the table.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Sharing your data is the one way we can help you or create reproducible example of your data and put that in your question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Aran! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I removed the bit where you were asking for recommendations of things, because that's not allowed as a question type here